# Are color schemes copyrightable?

Tags: copyright

For instance the video game World of Warcraft has a color scheme for classes (can be seen at: https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Class_colors) and item rarity (white, green, blue, purple and orange).

Does copyright apply in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "scheme" is likely not protected by copyright. See generally [In the United States, what is the threshold for "originality" in order to have copyright protection?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/87627/46948) and [17 U.S.C. 102](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#102) (especially 102(b)).

A "scheme" is not an "original work of authorship"; it's an idea or method of associating certain colors with certain meanings. The United States Copyright Office has said it "cannot register a claim to copyright in color in and of itself or a system for matching pairs and sets of colors" (U.S. Copyright Office, [*Copyright of U.S. Copyright Office Practices*, s. 313.4(K)](https://www.copyright.gov/comp3/docs/compendium.pdf#page=80)).

<sup>See also [this Q & A](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/can-ups-really-trademark-the-color-brown) about trademark in color.</sup>